# Display GIF as Facebook link thumbnail

Tags: html

Can someone help me, please?
I'm trying to figure how I can display GIFS directly on Facebook along  with the URL.

I see many sites that can do this, like this one: https://www.gif-vif.com/

However, I don't know how to do the same with my website.

Comment: I'd guess this is [Open Graph Markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup). There will be plenty of plugins that can generate this for you already e.g. SEO plugins.

Comment: I've tried with the Yoast SEO and it didn't worked. It keep showing just the link with static image.

Comment: The URL the opengraph thumbnail/image uses on that site is an animated GIF, that's all there is to it, there is no special code or trick. If you need to adjust Yoast to support this you will need to ask this in a Yoast SEO community, or via Yoast support. Otherwise you are going to need to share the code you are debugging. Remember, this is a technical stack for programmers, so any answer you get will require basic programming knowledge to understand.

Comment: As I can see I need to change something on the og:url. However, I don't know exactly what I need to change